# SnowSQL Bad Handshake when running PUT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I am trying to PUT a file from local workstation to a named stage I created but getting an SSL error:

**("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)**

I am able to run SELECT statements from within SnowSQL and they run with no problems. But when I try to do a PUT I  get an error.

I have also installed latest SnowSQL version available but no luck.

Any thoughts on why I would be getting this error?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

My initial thoughts are that the error indicates a firewall or proxy issue. In particular, a proxy might intercept Snowflake's SSL certificate and replace it with their own. The best way to resolve this is to ensure the certificate is trusted in the proxy and the proxy is configured as per Snowflake's documentation so that the Snowflake certificate can pass through.

The documentation below has more information on using a proxy with SnowSQL. You can pass along the error with issuer details to your network engineer and can request to whitelist the required URLs (documentation also below outlining the whitelisting requirements). You can use the SYSTEM$WHITELIST function to get all the URLs to whitelist in a proxy or firewall for your account.

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#using-a-proxy-server
- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/hostname-whitelist.html